# Trim transparent pixels from a layered Photoshop document (.psd)

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

How can I trim transparent pixels from a layered Photoshop document (.psd)? I wish to also remove areas hidden by clipping masks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with `//trim image to transparent width
app.activeDocument.trim(TrimType.TRANSPARENT, true, true, true, true);`

Comment: @GhoulFool yeah that's valid. i didn't realize it was supported in the object reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will trim document transparency and remove masked areas. It is generated by ScriptListener for the menu item Image > Trim with the settings shown. Minor code cleanup for readability.

[image: Image > Trim Settings]

```js
function trimDocTransparency() {
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor()
  var idtrimBasedOn = stID( "trimBasedOn" )
  desc.putEnumerated( idtrimBasedOn, idtrimBasedOn, chID( "Trns" ) )
  desc.putBoolean( chID( "Top " ), true )
  desc.putBoolean( chID( "Btom" ), true )
  desc.putBoolean( chID( "Left" ), true )
  desc.putBoolean( chID( "Rght" ), true )
  executeAction( stID( "trim" ), desc, DialogModes.NO )
} // trimDocTransparency

function chID( a ) { return charIDToTypeID( a )}
function stID( a ) { return stringIDToTypeID( a )}
```

To use this solution, open & activate the intended document and then invoke the function in your script like this:

```
trimDocTransparency()
```